# How can each Combobox get its own SQL?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I am using Python 3 and TKinter. I need second combo to load info based on first combo selection. The second Combobox comes up empty after selection in first combobox.

The first combo does the right thing but the second doesn't get pull any info even though the I am using the same sort of code.

I've tried combining the SQL statements and that doesn't help me either. What am I doing wrong? It goes without saying that I'm a beginner.

Here is my code:

```
from os import name
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import random
#======= IMPORTS COMBOBOX =============
from tkinter import ttk
from sqlite3 import Error
from tkinter.font import BOLD
    

def Clear(event):

    usernameLabel.config(textvariable=' ')
    passwordLabel.config(textvariable=' ')
    
    print('It worked')

def Str3f(event):
    global Str3
    Str3 = Person_Combo.get()
    print(Str3)
    
    #   SQL CONNECTION TO TABLE "NAMES"
    sqlName = sqlite3.connect('Pass.db')
    c2 = sqlName.cursor()
    c2.execute('SELECT Name FROM Passwords WHERE Person= ?', (Str3, ))
    # WHERE Person= ?', (Str3, ))

    global mydata2
    mydata2 = c2.fetchall()

    # global Namers2
    # Namers2 = [mydata2]
    c2.close()
    sqlName.close()


def EnterClick():

    global Str1
    global Str2
    global UName
    global UPass
    
    Str1 = Person_Combo.get()
    Str2 = Name_Combo.get()
    print(Str2)

    UName = StringVar()
    UPass = StringVar()

    connection = sqlite3.connect('Pass.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Passwords WHERE Person= ? AND Name= ?', (Str1, Str2, ))
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    
    UName.set('Username:  ' + record[4])
    UPass.set('Password:  ' + record[5])

    usernameLabel.config(textvariable=UName, font=("Halvetica", 16))
    passwordLabel.config(textvariable=UPass, font=("Halvetica", 16))

    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

#   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#=========== MAIN WINDOW ===============

root = Tk()

root.geometry('500x700')
root.title('Password Saver')
my_menu = Menu(root)



#   CREATE LABELS AND TEXT ENTRY TO DISPLAY RESULTS
TopLabel = Label(root, text='PASSWORD SAVER', font=('Halvetica 20'))
TopLabel.pack(pady=30)

#     SQL CONNECTION TO TABLE "PERSON"
sqlPerson = sqlite3.connect('Pass.db')
c1 = sqlPerson.cursor()
# c2 = sqlPerson.cursor()
c1.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Person FROM Passwords')
# c2.execute('SELECT Name From Passwords')
mydata1 = c1.fetchall()
# mydata2 = c2.fetchall()

Namers = [mydata1]
# Namers2 = [mydata2]
c1.close()
# c2.close()
sqlPerson.close()


    #     Create a person combobox
Person_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=mydata1)
Person_Combo.pack(pady=20)
# Person_Combo.bind('<FocusIn>')

global Str3
Str3 = Person_Combo.get()
print(Str3)

#   SQL CONNECTION TO TABLE "NAMES"
sqlName = sqlite3.connect('Pass.db')
c2 = sqlName.cursor()
c2.execute('SELECT Name FROM Passwords WHERE Person= ?', (Str3, ))
# WHERE Person= ?', (Str3, ))

mydata2 = c2.fetchall()

c2.close()
sqlName.close()

#     Create a results combobox
Name_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=mydata2)
Name_Combo.pack(pady=20)



Button1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=EnterClick)
Button1.pack(pady=20)

usernameLabel = Label(root,)
usernameLabel.pack()

passwordLabel = Label(root, )
passwordLabel.pack()

Person_Combo.bind('<FocusIn>', Clear)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you try to get the selected value from `Person_Combo` just after it is created, you should get empty string and so you should not get any result from the database.

You need to do the above inside a function (most likely `Str3f()`) which is triggered when an item of `Person_Combo` is selected.  It can be done by binding the virtual event `<<ComboboxSelected>>`:

```py
def Str3f(event):
    #global Str3
    Str3 = Person_Combo.get()
    print(Str3)

    #   SQL CONNECTION TO TABLE "NAMES"
    sqlName = sqlite3.connect('Pass.db')
    c2 = sqlName.cursor()
    c2.execute('SELECT Name FROM Passwords WHERE Person = ?', (Str3, ))

    #global mydata2
    mydata2 = [row[0] for row in c2.fetchall()]

    Name_Combo["values"] = mydata2  # update Name_Combo
    Name_Combo.set("")  # clear selection of Name_Combo

    c2.close()
    sqlName.close()

...

#     Create a person combobox
Person_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=mydata1)
Person_Combo.pack(pady=20)
# Person_Combo.bind('<FocusIn>')
Person_Combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", Str3f)

#     Create a results combobox
Name_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root) # no values assigned initially
Name_Combo.pack(pady=20)

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I was trying to use it in a function but wasn't anything to show in the Name_Combo. I was using it bound to focus though. I will try binding it to ComboboxSelected later tonight and let you know if that did the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much... You're amazing. You solved my problem that I couldn't get my brain around.